# web2py convert Storage object to string

Tags: python, json, web2py

I have some RESTful API calls in web2py which take in JSON file. I make the calls through the command line using curl like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @mydata.json https://mywebsite/doWork
```

In my web2py controller I have it setup to read the POST request. When I examine request.vars by returning it, it contains the full JSON data, but request.vars is of type: class 'gluon.storage.Storage'.

I need the data in string format in the controller. However, if I do str(request.vars), web2py appends a Storage tag in front of my data.

```
@request.restful()
def doWork():

    def POST(*args, **vars):
        return(request.vars)

    return locals()
```

Assuming the mydata.json file is something simple like:

{
    "key": "value"
}

The request to POST will return {"key": "value"} as a gluon.storage.Storage object.

If I change the line return(request.vars) to return(str(request.vars)) the output is now: < Storage {u'key': u'value'}>

How can I convert this request.vars to a string without it appending the Storage tag to the front, and changing the double quotes to single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert `vars` back to JSON, you can use the Python `json` library or just use `response.json`:

```
    return response.json(vars)
```

Alternatively, you can add the `.json` extension to the request and simply return  `vars` directly:

```
    return vars
```

with the following request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @mydata.json https://mywebsite/doWork.json
```

In that case, web2py will automatically convert the response to JSON.

Comment: When I use response.json(request.vars) it escapes the double-quotations with backslashes. Is there a way to have it not escape the double quotes? 

For example, I get back: "{\"key\": \"value\"}"

Comment: The response does not have escaped quotation marks -- that must just be related to how you are viewing the response (when I use `curl` with this same code, the response printed in the console does not show any escaped quotes -- same thing when making the request from a browser).

Comment: I got it working it now. Using just 'vars' instead of 'request.vars' was a big help because request.vars was of type gluon Storage, and vars by itself was of type dict. To use the JSON as a string within my code I was able to do str(json.dumps(vars)). Thank you for the help.

Comment: `Storage` inherits from `dict`, so it shouldn't make a difference whether you use `request.vars` or `vars`. Also, `json.dumps` returns a string, so no need to then pass it to `str()`.